# Difference between current stop and start time in android studio java language

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have two button start and stop. it get current time when i click on these button and show me the current time in textview. i want to make diffienece between these textview time and want to add the start, stop and difference of time to save in sql database.
my code is here.

```
public class Aircraft extends Fragment {

    TextView tvstarttime;
    Button btn_start;
    Button btn_end;
    TextView tvend;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_aircraft, container, false);

        tvstarttime = view.findViewById(R.id.txtstarttime);
        btn_start = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_start);
        btn_end= view.findViewById(R.id.btn_end);
        tvend = view.findViewById(R.id.txtendtime);
       btn_start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {

               Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
               SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss aa");
               String time = format.format(calendar.getTime());


               tvstarttime.setText(time);
           }
       });
        btn_end.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss aa");
                String time = format.format(calendar.getTime());


                tvend.setText(time);
            }
        });


        return view;
    }






}
```

Comment: Where is sql here?

Comment: can u help me only find difference between these two textview time and save that difference in to new textview. than later i will insert these textview into database.

Comment: In that case you might want to remove any mentioning of SQL from your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can find difference between two timestamp and store it to your db like,

```
 long startTime = 0L;
 long endTime = 0L;
    
    btn_start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                // Do your code here
           
           Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
           SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss aa");
           String time = format.format(calendar.getTime());


           tvstarttime.setText(time);
    
                startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    
               }
    });

    btn_end.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
               // Do your code here
   
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss aa");
            String time = format.format(calendar.getTime());


            tvend.setText(time);

                endTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
                }
    });
    
    //calculate Time difference, but make sure you have put proper validations for end time and start time so difference can not be negative

    difference = endTime - startTime
```

Comment: i want to also show start and stop time in textview. and then find difference. because i have to insert three thing into database, start time stop time and difference. u share code  doesnot show start and stop time in textview.