# Get start and stop time with one button in android studio java language

Tags: java, android, sql, android-studio

I made two button when click on start button it show current time in text view. when click on stop button it also show current time in text view. than calculate difference between these time.
my problem is that when i click on multiple time on button it continuously change time. I want that both start and stop time get with single click. I mean that i have one button when click on that button it show current start time in Textview and turn text of that button to stop then when again click on that button show stop time and calculate difference of both time and show in textview.Later on i have to save all three textview time in SQL database.

```
public class Aircraft extends Fragment {

    TextView tvstarttime;
    Button btn_start;
    Button btn_end;
    TextView tvend;
    TextView diffence;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_aircraft, container, false);

        tvstarttime = view.findViewById(R.id.txtstarttime);
        btn_start = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_start);
        btn_end= view.findViewById(R.id.btn_end);
        tvend = view.findViewById(R.id.txtendtime);
        diffence=view.findViewById(R.id.txtdifference);
       btn_start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {

               Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
               SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss aa");
              String time1 = format.format(calendar.getTime());


               tvstarttime.setText(time1);
           }
       });
        btn_end.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss aa");
                String time = format.format(calendar.getTime());


                tvend.setText(time);
                try {
                    Date date1 = format.parse(tvend.getText().toString());
                    Date date2 = format.parse(tvstarttime.getText().toString());
                    long mills = date1.getTime() - date2.getTime();
                    Log.v("Data1", ""+date1.getTime());
                    Log.v("Data2", ""+date2.getTime());
                    int hours = (int) (mills/(1000 * 60 * 60));
                    int mins = (int) (mills % (1000*60*60));

                    String diff = hours + ":" + mins;
                    diffence.setText(diff);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



            }
        });


        return view;
    }






}
```

Comment: Consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. Use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) in order to use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between current stop and start time in android studio java language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72009201/difference-between-current-stop-and-start-time-in-android-studio-java-language)

Comment: yes. can u help me for editing my code according to condition . it show start and stop time and make differenece i want to show four time, enter , start, stop and exit time with same button. and than calculate the differnece between start and stop time.

Answer (score 0):

public class Aircraft extends Fragment {

```
TextView tvstarttime;
Button btn_start;
TextView tvend;
TextView diffence;

boolean isStarted = false;



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_aircraft, container, false);

    tvstarttime = view.findViewById(R.id.txtstarttime);
    btn_start = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_start);
    tvend = view.findViewById(R.id.txtendtime);
    diffence=view.findViewById(R.id.txtdifference);
    btn_start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (isStarted){
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss aa");
                String time = format.format(calendar.getTime());


                tvend.setText(time);
                try {
                    Date date1 = format.parse(tvend.getText().toString());
                    Date date2 = format.parse(tvstarttime.getText().toString());
                    long mills = date1.getTime() - date2.getTime();
                    Log.v("Data1", ""+date1.getTime());
                    Log.v("Data2", ""+date2.getTime());
                    int hours = (int) (mills/(1000 * 60 * 60));
                    int mins = (int) (mills % (1000*60*60));

                    String diff = hours + ":" + mins;
                    diffence.setText(diff);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                btn_start.setText("START");
            }else {
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss aa");
                String time1 = format.format(calendar.getTime());


                tvstarttime.setText(time1);
                btn_start.setText("STOP");
            }
            isStarted = !isStarted;



        }
    });
    


    return view;
}
```

}

Comment: Thank u so much. its working. can u give me a little bit more. i have to save this start and stop time into sql database. i want that it can only enter just one start , stop and difference of time . i mean when click on stop button then save the data in database. then textview should be empty automatically.

Comment: can u help me by editing above code. i want to get four time, enter, start, stop and exit time then calculate difference between the start and stop time. with the same button.